# What is the meaning of this command to install dot net framework on EC2 Windows instance?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-ec2

I used this command in UserData section to install dot net framework on EC2 Windows instance.

```
Install-WIndowsFeature Net-Framework-Core -source C:\Windows\WinSxS
```

I want to know what is WinSxS folder and what is its role in this command?

Answer (score 2):

It is simply telling powershell where to look for the files, in this case the WinSxs folder on your local machine.

This article explains what the WInSxS folder is for:

https://www.thewindowsclub.com/winsxs-folder-windows-7-8